# when i do any operation on cell ( tableview) and saved something,the image should come with same data in clicked cell using wpf c# mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

This is what I have tried . . .
[image: DevExpress Slection Range] 
created datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="colBirthDateCellTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="abc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Image  Margin="4,0,4,0" Source="E:\Development\C5FA\ProFDAnalyzer\Images\Note-04.png" Visibility="{Binding ImageVisble,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},ElementName=tranSummaryTableView}" Height="10" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="Note Saved" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Image>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And by calling this template by celltemplate each cell is coming with the image but data is getting hide.where in the datatemplate the textblock cant be bind with the datatable property.so plese help to do the same.

here is the grid xaml

```
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView  x:Name="tranSummaryTableView" ShowTotalSummary="True" AllowBestFit="True"  WaitIndicatorType="Default" ClipboardCopyWithHeaders="False" 
                    NavigationStyle="Cell" Focusable="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource colBirthDateCellTemplate}" AllowEditing="False" EditorShowMode="MouseUp" MultiSelectMode="Cell"  ShowGroupPanel="False" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: What is `tranSummaryTableView` ans why are you bindng to it? Do you have a view model with a `ImageVisible` property? Also, what do you mean by "data is getting hide"?

Comment: thanks for the reply
The tranSummaryTableView is the tableview Name,
imagevisible is a bool property which is getting true after having some operation by clicking on the cell.
And Databinding means binded the itemsource property where bulk of data is coming into to the tablview.

Comment: Actully i need when some operation has been done by clicking cell.the cell should update with the image so that some operation has been done on that cell.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the forum. You don't appear to be using data binding. Am I correct in assuming that you don't have any separate ViewModel code?

Comment: Your requirement is not quite clear enough. Can you please post your `DataGrid` xaml and any relevent view models.

Comment: Need to done -                                                                                                                                    After rgt click on cell some notes to be saved.after saved the clicked cell should be update with an image.which represents some notes saved on the same cell.

Comment: OK. You still haven't shown any view model code, you've tagged this with mvvm so I'm assuming you are using view models? I'm still unsure why you're binding to `tranSummaryTableView`? As I asked in my first comment, do you have a view model with a `ImageVisible` property? Also, have you looked at https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/6084/controls-and-libraries/data-grid? it looks like there's some pretty good documentation

Comment: have the viewmodel for the rgt clcik operation on the cell for note saving.in this saving mothod imagevisible property getting enable to appear on the cell.but it is showing for the all cells within the tableview.

Comment: What happens if you remove `ElementName=tranSummaryTableView`

Comment: if i remove ElementName=tranSummaryTableView even the imagevisible property lost control(default = true).and same data getting hide only image coming in all the cells.